# Proof explanation - Existence of second derivative of characteristic function at 0 implies finite second moment

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

> Existence of second derivative of characteristic function of r.v. X at 0 implies
> that the second moment of X is finite.

There is a proof of that statement in Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory" (2001 edition, Theorem 6.4.1 - even more general, but it involves doing that for k = 2) which has one transition I can't wrap my mind around. It goes as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
\varphi^{(2)}_X(0) 
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\varphi(h)-2\varphi(0)+\varphi(-h)}{h^2} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ihx}-2+e^{-ihx}}{h^2}\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) 
= -2 \lim_{h \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1 - \cos(hx)}{h^2}\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)
\end{split}
$$

On the other hand, by Fatou's Lemma:

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X^2] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) 
&=  2  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{1 - \cos(hx)}{h^2}\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) \\
&\leq 2 \liminf_{h \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   \frac{1 - \cos(hx)}{h^2}\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) = -\varphi^{(2)}_X(0) < \infty
\end{split}
$$
QED.

Now, I want to know why the following part in second line is true:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)
=  2  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{1 - \cos(hx)}{h^2}\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)
$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $$\lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{1 - \cos(hx)}{h^2}=\frac{x^2}2$$
which can be seen by Taylor's expansion.

Comment: Yes, h was supposed to go to 0 - I have edited the original question. Now the proof is clear, thank you.

Comment: Then I suppressed the first part of the answer since it is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with Davide Giraudo. Indeed the limit is easily verified:
$$\cos(\alpha) = 1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2!} + \dfrac{\alpha^4}{4!} - \dfrac{\alpha^6}{6!} +...$$
$$1-\cos(hx) = \dfrac{h^2x^2}{2} - \dfrac{h^4 x^4}{4!} + \dfrac{h^6x^6}{6!} +...$$
$$\dfrac{1-\cos(hx)}{h^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{2} - \dfrac{h^2 x^4}{4!} + \dfrac{h^4x^6}{6!} +...$$
and as you can see the limit for $h\to 0 $ is clearly what expected:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos(hx)}{h^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{2}$$